# Python сохранение dict в json с кириллицой

Tags: python

Хочу сохранить dict в json.

Сохраняю так:

```
def save_json(json_text, output_filename):
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_text)
```

Кириллица в виде кодов в файле.
Пытался вот так

```
def save_json(json_text, output_filename):
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_text, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Кидает AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dump', убрал, переименовал, теперь последний вариант возвращает

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20bd' in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: У вас в коде где-то есть словарь с именем `json`?

Comment: @Andrey переименовал переменную

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def save_json(json_text, output_filename):
    with open(output_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_text, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```